# UnknownHostException only on Bluemix

Tags: docker, ibm-cloud, inetaddress

We're encountering an UnknownHostException when our application calls java.net.InetAddress.getLocalHost(). This issue is only seen when our docker image (built from registry.ng.Bluemix.net/ibmliberty) runs in Bluemix. Running the same container on non-Bluemix hosts yield successful responses from the method. While most of the call locations use this value for information purposes and /etc/hostname holds the instance name of the container, we don't want to write special code to look into that file. The hope was that use of a Bluemix scaling group would resolve this issue because it takes a --hostname= parameter, but it does not.

Since this only occurs when running in Bluemix, this seems like an issue in how Bluemix is instantiating its images.

Is this a known issue and are there plans to address it? Or are there measures we can take when invoking our images that resolve this issue?

Here's the stack trace fragment:

```
Caused by:
     java.net.UnknownHostException: instance-00024443: Name or service not known
         at java.net.InetAddress$1.lookupAllHostAddr(InetAddress.java:1021)
         at java.net.InetAddress.getAddressesFromNameService(InetAddress.java:1432)
         at java.net.InetAddress.getLocalHost(InetAddress.java:1649)
         ... 38 more
```

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of [known issues](https://www.ng.bluemix.net/docs/containers/container_troubleshoot.html#ts_known_issues) with the networking not responding immediately after creating containers. Can you try delaying this call for sixty seconds to see if this resolves the issue?

Comment: Thanks James.  I just tried this, but it didn't change any behavior.  I didn't expect it to work since we have background tasks periodically making this call that fail (well after startup) - but I wanted to eliminate the possibility that perhaps we're initializing something (to a bad and persistent state) by making an early call.